# must a continuous function into hilbert space with all differences perpendicular be constant?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, continuity

If $H$ is a Hilbert space and $f:[0,1]\rightarrow H$ is a continuous function such that $f(x)-f(y)\perp f(y)-f(z)$ whenever $x<y<z$, does $f$ have to be constant?

By Pythagoras's theorem, the given condition is equivalent to $|f(x)-f(y)|^2+|f(y)-f(z)|^2=|f(x)-f(z)|^2$ for all $x<y<z$. If we can prove this has no nontrivial solutions in $\mathbb{R}$, then the answer will be yes.

On the other hand, there are uncountably many perpendicular vectors in $H$ (it can't be countably infinte-dimensional), so maybe the answer should be no. I think it's possible to get the required equation holding for all $x$, $z$ for some fixed $y$, just by taking $\ell_2$ and using lots of zero components to make sure everything is perpendicular.

Many thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

False: Take $f(x)=1_{[0,x]}$ maping $[0,1]$ into $L_2[0,1]$

Comment: Nice example - thanks!